# Jtable cannot sort Integer or Double

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, comparator

I have a table with 5 columns (1-2-3 String 4 Integer 5 Double)
when I try to sort the table by the last two column it sorts incorrectly.

I tried to use a comparator but get **IndexOutOfBoundsException** for my tablemodel

```
private String[] colonne  = {"Barcode", "Modello", "Descrizione", 
                                "Quantitativo", "prezzo"};

//other code

DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(colonne, 0);

//other code

table = new JTable(tableModel);

TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(tableModel);


sorter.setComparator(0, new Comparator<String>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2)
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(o1) - Integer.parseInt(o2);
            }
        });



table.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

If your columns contain Integer and Double objects, then you need to override the `getColumnClass(...)` method of your `TableModel` to tell the table what the class of the column is:

```
@Overide
public Class getColumnClass(int column)
{
    if (column == 4)
        return Double.class;
    else if (column == 3)
        return Integer.class;
    else
        return String.class;
}
```

Then the table will use the appropriate Comparator. You don't need to create a custom Comparator.